# Cursor giving error while populating it to a ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, cursor

This is an headache I am trying it from a long but still no where this code giving me error

MainActivity.class

```
    try{
    handler = new DataHandler(this);
    handler.open();
    c = handler.getAllMainData();   
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            CampaignId.add(c.getInt(0), null);
            CampaignName.add(c.getString(1));
            Message.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("message")));
            StartDate.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("start_date")));
            Repeat.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("repeat")));    
            c.moveToNext();
    }
    handler.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Error",e.toString());
    }
```

getAllMainData in DataHelper Class

```
public Cursor getAllMainData(){
    String sql= "SELECT * FROM "+CampaignMain_TABLE;
    return db.rawQuery(sql, null);
}
```

Error is 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0

Select * From campaign_name will retrive more columns then i am selecting in the MainActivity // I guess that shouldnt be aproblem but just for becoming more descriptive

Comment: 1. Step through the code with the debugger and find where the error occurs. 2. Disparate arrays and lists are a headache to manage. Make a class representing the entity/model (perhaps call it `Campaign`) and use a list of that. When you read the cursor, make a `Campaign` object for each row, read in the properties, and add it to the list. 3. You should not be querying your database in `onCreate()` or on the main UI thread in general. Learn about AsyncTask, Loaders, and other asynchronous loading techniques.

Comment: I need to view it on the main screen thats why its oncreate

Comment: "I need to view it on the main screen thats why its oncreate" -- so does everyone else who makes an Android app. Just because it needs to be **displayed** does not mean it needs to be **loaded** on the main thread. I'm not saying you have to do it right now, but if you plan on making your app production quality, you need to keep I/O operations like this off the main thread; Android provides a number of ways to do this and there are plenty of guides.

Comment: @Karakuri Thats not my question but

Answer (score 0):

At which line exactly you are getting IndexOutOfBoundsException exception? Are you sure your cursor is not null/empty? I think it should be like this:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        // Read data from cursor
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Not working I tried it but still getting the out of bound error

Comment: Can you tell me exactly at which line you are getting the error? Post the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Actually i got it solve this is the problem of List<Integer> when i use this as List<String> for the first value CampaignId.add(c.getInt(0), null); it work fine without any error

Comment: I think I got the root cause of the error but don't know how List<string> can resolve the issue. The issue is you have used add method of list with 2 params where 1st stands for index in the list where value is to be added and 2nd one stand for the value to be added. So you are just retrieving value from database and using it as index and putting null value in the list every time. And the integer value you are getting from database is greater then the list size, that's why throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBound error.

Comment: Just go for CampaignId.add(c.getInt(0)). It will add element at the end of the list.

Comment: Another thing which has nothing to do with the issue... you are calling c.moveToNext() twice which will skip alternate records from database. And why on earth you are using two while conditions for same body?

Comment: It was by mistake @prashant

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
// Read data
}
```

Comment: You need to put more detail in here.